# get count while also using top in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Request.ID) AS count, 
    ClaimHandlingStatusID AS statusId
FROM 
    Request
GROUP BY
    ClaimHandlingStatusID 
ORDER BY 
    ClaimHandlingStatusID
```

which returns a result like this:

```
count    statusId
-----------------
5        -1
5        1
2321     5
27008    6
95288    8
```

However, I would like to only show the most recent top 500 of `request.ID` (the `Request` table has a `createddate` column). So that the query will only show the top 500 `RequestId`, and thereafter show how many of these 500 have the different `statusId`.

Here are some queries I have tried (that do not work):

```
SELECT COUNT(Request.ID) AS count, ClaimHandlingStatusID AS statusId
FROM Request 
WHERE Request.ID = (SELECT TOP 500 (ID) FROM Request 
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate desc)
GROUP BY ClaimHandlingStatusID 
ORDER BY ClaimHandlingStatusID 

SELECT TOP 500 
    ID, COUNT(*) Total, 
    ClaimHandlingStatusID AS statusId
FROM Request
GROUP BY ClaimHandlingStatusID
ORDER BY ClaimHandlingStatusID
```

Desired outcome would be something like:

```
count    statusId
------------------
50        -1
50        1
100       5
150       6
150       8
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `SUM()` as an analytic function to find the total rolling count, then restrict to only records whose total is less than or equal to 500:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, ClaimHandlingStatusID AS statusId,
           SUM(count) OVER (ORDER BY ClaimHandlingStatusID) AS total
    FROM Request
    GROUP BY ClaimHandlingStatusID
)

SELECT count, statusId
FROM cte
WHERE total <= 500
ORDER BY statusId;
```